# How to read numbers in text file as numbers in to list?

Tags: python

I have a text file in which there are numbers in each line(only numbers). My `color.txt` looks like:

```
3
3
5
1
5
1
5
```

When I read this to list using

```
f=open('D:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\color.txt',"r")
    for line in f:
        g_colour_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    print g_colour_list
```

the output is like

```
['3', '3', '5', '1', '5', '1', '5']
```

But I want it as:

```
[3,3,5,1,5,1,5]
```

How can I do that in the single line that is
`g_colour_list.append(line.strip('\n'))`?

Comment: So...you have a list of strings, and you want a list of integers.  I bet you can find instructions for converting numeric strings to integers if you look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just cast your strings into integers:

```
g_colour_list.append(int(line.strip('\n')))
```

Comment: There is no need to strip, as `int()` ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a call to python's `int` function which converts a digit string to a number around your `line.strip()` call:

```
f=open('D:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\color.txt',"r")
    for line in f:
        g_colour_list.append(int(line.strip('\n')))
    print g_colour_list
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to cast the string to integer on appending. You can do it this way :

```
g_colour_list.append(int(line.strip('\n')))
```

If you think you will get floats as well then you should use `float()` instead of `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f:
    g_colour_list.append(int(line.strip('\n')))
```

You can parse a string s to int with int(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast it to int, doing:

```
f = open('color.txt',"r")
g_colour_list=[]

for line in f:
    g_colour_list.append(int(line.strip('\n')))

print (g_colour_list)
```